# BibTeX error: Use of \l doesn't match its definition

Tags: bibtex, accents

I currently have a LaTeX file with many defined macros.

I noticed an error I get in my `refs.bib` file which contains
only one BibTeX entry currently, as follows:

```
@Article{     latal1997,
  author    = {Lata\l a, Rafa\l},
  title     = {Estimation of moments of sums of independent real random
          variables},
  journal   = {Ann. Probab.},
  fjournal  = {The Annals of Probability},
  volume    = {25},
  year      = {1997},
  number    = {3},
  pages     = {1502--1513},
  issn      = {0091-1798},
  mrclass   = {60E15 (60G50)},
  mrnumber  = {1457628},
  mrreviewer    = {Pawel Hitczenko},
  doi       = {10.1214/aop/1024404522}
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Use of \l doesn't match its definition.

<write> ...rvs}{{\the \c@NAT@ctr }{1997}{{Lata\l ~
                                                  a}}{{}}}
l.3 ... 1997]{latala1997estimationmomentsindeprvs}
                                                  
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

The issue appears to be with the specific accent character `\l` in
LaTeX. I've tested with other accents e.g. `\L atala` and there
is no such error.

Clearly one of the macros or packages seems to have a conflict with this
specific accent being used in both BibTeX and the main LaTeX file.

I'm unable to provide a full reproducible example since the file
contains several hundred lines of macros.

Would anyone be able to assist in helping resolving this accent issue?

Comment: In BibTeX you should wrap macro escapes for non-ASCII chars in braces, so *`author = {Lata\l a, Rafa\l},` should be `author = {Lata{\l}a, Rafa{\l}},` **But** that will probably not solve your problem. It looks a bit like someone may have redefined `\l` a bit. I did not manage to reproduce the issue in a short example I came up with, so please consider posting a fully compilable example document that reproduces the error (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: @moewe - thanks. I did try this, but as you suspected it still did not solve the issue. I'm not sure how to compress this to a reproducible example given the complexity of the file. The alternative question is, can I override the definition temporarily?

Comment: Oh! you helped find the issue. Someone had defined macros of this form `\def\l({\left(}`, `\def\r){\right)}`, `\def\l[{\left[}`, `\def\r]{\right]}`. Commenting them out solved the problem

Comment: @user4687531 Just for completeness: if one does `\def\l({...}\def\l[{...}` then every occurrence of `\l(` will bomb out. Check your document for other similar errors and remove everything with `\def`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was due to careless redefinition of important commands, though unknown to the OP.

Comment: @egreg - many thanks for your additional explanation. And totally understand if you want to close this.

Comment: @user4687531 Yes, not your fault, but the question is not likely to help anyone besides you. At least I hope that kind of bad code won't spread. ;-)

Comment: @egreg - I've definitely removed those offending macros, so rest assured that it won't spread further :)